# XMLHttpRequest проблемы с "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Есть страница по адресу https://yobit.net/api/3/ticker/btc_rur. У меня есть следующий Javascript код:

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open("GET", "https://yobit.net/api/3/ticker/btc_rur", false);
r.send();
```

Во время его выполнения браузер выдаёт ошибку:

> Failed to load https://yobit.net/api/3/ticker/btc_rur: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.6' is therefore not allowed access.

Я пробовал добавить следующие строки в код перед `r.send();`:

```
r.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
r.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Появляется такая ошибка:

> Failed to load https://yobit.net/api/3/ticker/btc_rur: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.6' is therefore not allowed access.

Подскажите, как исправить ошибку.

---

Пробовал ещё способ через jQuery, тоже не работает:

```
$.getJSON("https://yobit.net/api/3/ticker/btc_rur", function (r) {
    var p = "{\"btc_rur\":{\"high\":${r.high},\"low\":${r.low},\"avg\":${r.avg},\"vol\":${r.vol},\"vol_cur\":${r.vol_cur},\"last\":${r.last},\"buy\":${r.buy},\"sell\":${r.sell},\"updated\":${r.updated}}}";
    alert(p.last);
});
```

Comment: как на счет **[вот этого](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgUDN.jpg)** ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не совсем то. Насколько я понял, моя проблема нерешаема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пришлось воспользоваться PHP (page.php):

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('https://yobit.net/api/3/ticker/btc_rur');
?>
```

(index.html):

```
...
<script>
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open("GET", "page.php", false);
r.send();
var j = JSON.parse(r.responseText); // <-- success array
...
</script>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

По-моему вы неправильно понимаете как работает технология CORS. Не клиент, а сервер устанавливает заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, а браузер пользователя, получив такой заголовок разрешает доступ к ресурсам этого домена, который не совпадает с текущим.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: Ок, допустим. Как быть тогда?

Comment: Ну я же написал, добавьте заголовок к ответу сервера.

Comment: У меня нет доступа к исходникам сервера

Comment: Тогда облом. Только JSONP.

Comment: через Jsonp - это как? Изменил вопрос, вы самый последний мой способ имеете ввиду (через jQuery)?

Comment: JSONP и JSON это разные вещи. Насколько я понял вам нужно получить данные с другого сервера.

Comment: Тогда просто проксируйте запросы через свой сервер